# How do I remove adaptive behavior from the v-menu component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to create an input field for the site where a search can be done using the `v-text-field` and the result will be displayed in the `v-menu` component.

The problem is that when the screen height is insufficient, the `v-menu` component covers the input field like this-

[image]

But I want it to be like this-

[image]

Here is my code-

```
<v-text-field
  :items="..."
  v-model="..."
  ...
>
  <v-menu activator="parent">
    ...
  </v-menu>
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: You have not included enough information to reproduce the issue, making your question unanswerable. Consider [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your project into codesandbox to provide a [mcve].

Comment: which version of Vuetify are you on?

Comment: Why not use `v-autocomplete`?

Comment: @NehaSoni , I am using Vuetify version 3.0.6.
I don't use v-autocomplete and v-combobox because they also have this problem

Comment: Did you try `attach` prop?

Comment: @NehaSoni , No, how can this be done?

Comment: Give some id to the parent of the menu and then attach the menu to its parent, like this- `<div id="parent"><v-menu attach="#parent"></v-menu></div>`

Comment: @Neha Soni, When I add the attach pass, the v-menu does not work at all